# POP server for default email client on ISPConfig

Tags: pop3, squirrelmail

I have [ISPConfig3](http://www.ispconfig.org/) server , where [SquirrelMail](http://squirrelmail.org) mail is already configured i have.

I am able to login to my email account https://www.mydomain:8080/webmail/src/webmail.php.

I want to configure this account with my yahoo account , which requires POP address for setup this account , how can i find that which is my SMTP and POP address.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not an ISPconfig cluster, your domain name is your POP3 server name.

If it is a cluster, you have to check which is the mail server and use that.